# Data has been sent via a http request client loopj but unable to retrieve using php

Tags: java, php, android, loopj

I know for a fact the data I am sending in this is getting sent unlike my previous question where an exception was being thrown. I can successfully execute a request object using loopj async http client however i am unable to get my data from the php side and display it, the status code that gets displayed is 200 which means the request library is working. I have a felling it maybe a firewall issue but not sure how to bypass that? Any tips on how to resolve this from the php side would be much appreciated.

here is my code:

```
 protected void PostData(final Integer Question_ID,Integer ResponseChosen_ID) throws IOException {
    try{
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        final RequestParams params1 = new RequestParams();
        params1.put("Question_ID", Question_ID.toString());
        params1.setUseJsonStreamer(true);
        client.get("http://cce.swlgroup.com/SwlLogin.php/", params1, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                messageBox("Response Successful: ", "" + statusCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("Response",error.toString());
            }
        });
        System.out.print(params1);
}
}
}
```

php code:

repo.php:

```
 var_dump($_SERVER);
 var_dump($_GET);
```

nothing is displayed here, im also not sure now what i am trying to do is even possible with the built in library and now a third party library.

Comment: Isn't your data in a `responseBody`?

Comment: ANd waht's he value of `responseBody`?

Comment: the value of response body is {B@e444ff6

Comment: what do i use to display it on a webpage as ive got html in the response body